# How can I programmatically install a mail server certificate into Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: installation, certificate, thunderbird

Does anybody know how to do it?
I have certificate for mail server. And I need to add it to 100500 workstations.

Comment: Windows clients? If so you could rely on the windows certificate store (https://superuser.com/questions/1026187/can-firefox-use-the-windows-certificate-store) and roll the certificate as well as the firefox settings by GPO...

Comment: In your link there talk about FireFox. I think Thunderbird and FireFox are different.